# Fold Results in VSCode Search Editor (*not* search explorer)

Tags: visual-studio-code, search, folding

I'm looking for a way to fold *all* results in a VSCode search editor. (It's clear how to do this in the search explorer.)

I can easily fold individual results with cmd+opt+[ but I want to fold *all* of the results. I'd actually like to be able to have that be the default.

[image: Editor Search Results]

Answer (score 0):

You can fold all the results by doing this:

1. Select all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. Command Palette: `Create Manual Folding Range From Selection`

That `Manual Folding Range` command has a default keybinding: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

You could put those two commands into a macro if you wanted, see the macro extension `multi-command`.

---

I don't think there is any way to have the Search Editor default to all folded - unless you put however you open that into the macro as well.

Doing that using [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), make this keybinding:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+w",      // whatever keybinding you want
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
      "interval": 500,   // you need some delay to open the editor first
      "sequence": [
        "search.action.openInEditor",
        "editor.action.selectAll",
        "editor.createFoldingRangeFromSelection"
      ]
    },
    "when": "hasSearchResult && searchViewletFocus"
  }
```

[image: folded search editor]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, none of that works as expected in the Search Editor.

* Selecting all and pressing cmd+opt+[ does nothing
* Selecting some of the results and pressing cmd+opt+[ folds only the first
* Selecting all and pressing cmd+k then cmd+, folds everything down to nothing--only the first result remains visible.

Comment: You want to fold each result separately then? Might still be able to do that... What do you want differently than your answer?

Comment: No, I want to fold them all at once, but not down to a single row. Just fold them to each result. So far, haven't seen way to do that.

Comment: I added an image at the end of my answer - is that the result you want in a single keybinding?  It can be achieved.  And how to invoke the Search Editor: with the `Open in Search Editor` button in a Search Panel or do you open a new empty Search Editor first and then enter your search terms there?

Answer (score 0):

I found the `cmd`+`k`, `cmd`+`0` will fold all up to the first line, but then I can open enough to see what I need. Not ideal, but useable.